# how to use an image in place of simple Node in reactFlow

Tags: reactjs, react-flow

I'm using 'reactflow' library in my react project
I'm trying to find a way to use an image in place of node so i can drag and move the image i want and also connect two images via edges
I have gone through the docs of reactflow but didn't find a solution
I don't know if its supported by library or not
Looking forward for any help.

Comment: You should share a minimal code to work with. But in your case, You've to create a custom node, as explained in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported by the [React Flow](https://reactflow.dev/) because React Flow's *["custom nodes are just React components, you can implement anything you need"](https://reactflow.dev/docs/concepts/introduction/#key-features)*.

You can create a [custom node](https://reactflow.dev/docs/examples/nodes/custom-node/) with a `div` as the node and then set the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) of the `div`, via CSS, with whatever you'd like. (Alternatively, you can use an [`img`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) element and set the `src` property.)

### `background-image` example:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { Handle, Position } from "reactflow";

export default memo(({ data, isConnectable }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Handle
        type="target"
        position={Position.Left}
        isConnectable={isConnectable}
      />
      <div
        style={{
          height: data.image.height,
          width: data.image.width,
          backgroundImage: `url(${data.image.url})`,
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
        }}
      />
      <Handle
        type="source"
        position={Position.Right}
        id="a"
        isConnectable={isConnectable}
      />
    </>
  );
});
```

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-flow-image-node-92kxwn?file=/ImageNode.js:0-789

***Or***

### `<img />` example:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { Handle, Position } from "reactflow";

export default memo(({ data, isConnectable }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Handle
        type="target"
        position={Position.Left}
        onConnect={(params) => console.log("handle onConnect", params)}
        isConnectable={isConnectable}
      />
      <img src={data.image.url} alt={data.image.alt} />
      <Handle
        type="source"
        position={Position.Right}
        id="a"
        isConnectable={isConnectable}
      />
    </>
  );
});
```

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/react-flow-image-node-img-nrt2xy?file=/ImageNode.js

### Both examples produce the following output:

[image: custom image node example output]